# when using uuid5 instead of sha1 the collision probability is the same?

Tags: python-2.7, hash, uuid

I need to create a unique hash but would like to maintain the ['uuid' structure,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) therefore I am thinking on using something like:

```
uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, 'python.org')
```

Instead of sha1:

```
hashlib.sha1('python.org').hexdigest()
```

But wondering, if they offer the same probability of collision, or maybe the uuid5 is more prone to collisions because of the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: avoid.

UUID5 truncates the hash to 128bits. While the 128 bits will be absolutely fine for most applications, the real issue is that you're using an outdated and deprecated hash algorithm in SHA1, and you're making it harder for yourself to change it later on.

In short: accidental collisions are *very* unlikely, but maliciously crafted collisions are becoming more and more feasible.

If at all possible, start with SHA2 or SHA3, and use a versioned object for your hash so you can change the algorithm in future.